# how to mock react-native-camera with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-camera

I am trying to test [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) module with [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/)

So I have the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.4.0-rc.4",
    "react-native": "0.40.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.0-rc.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

And given the following `Component` as it is in the [example](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/blob/master/Example/Example.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

class CameraComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.camera = null;

    this.state = {
      camera: {
        aspect: Camera.constants.Aspect.stretch,
        captureTarget: Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.cameraRoll,
        type: Camera.constants.Type.back,
        orientation: Camera.constants.Orientation.auto,
        flashMode: Camera.constants.FlashMode.auto,
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={this.state.camera.aspect}
          captureTarget={this.state.camera.captureTarget}
          type={this.state.camera.type}
          flashMode={this.state.camera.flashMode}
          defaultTouchToFocus
          mirrorImage={false}
        />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  preview: {
    flex: 1
  }
}
```

So the test below is failing with the following message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Aspect' of undefined

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Index from '../index.ios.js';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Index />
  );
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix that created `react-native-camera` react component in `__mocks__` folder:

```
import React from 'react';

const constants = constants = {
  Aspect: {},
  BarCodeType: {},
  Type: {},
  CaptureMode: {},
  CaptureTarget: {},
  CaptureQuality: {},
  Orientation: {},
  FlashMode: {},
  TorchMode: {}
};

class Camera extends React.Component {

  static constants = constants
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

Camera.constants = constants;

export default Camera;
```

And modified the test by adding the following lines:

```
import mockCamera from '../__mocks__/Camera';

jest.mock('react-native-camera', () => mockCamera);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to mock it using the name of the library and name of the component like this:

`jest.mock('react-native-camera', () => 'Camera');`

More info here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#tips

Comment: thanks, but I am affraid it is not that way, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you also importing it into your test? `import Camera from 'react-native-camera';
`

Comment: yes, but it looks like they need `constant` in the constructor

Comment: The point is that the mock instead of returning a string needs to return an object like this: `{constants: {Aspect: ....}}`